# MVVM-WPF: Dynamic view and memory leak?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, memory-leaks

I have a long-lived ViewModel and a dynamic View that is added to the visual tree whenever the user wants to see the ViewModel. When the user closes the View, it is removed from the visual tree. I intentionally put 50mb of dummy data in the View(UserControl):

```
private byte[] data = new byte[50 * 1024 * 1024];
```

I watched the Process Explorer memory shoots up when I add the View onto the visual tree. I closed the View(unloading it from the visual tree) and then explicitly called the Garbage collect method:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
```

However, the memory didn't reduced and whenever i add the View onto the visual tree, another 50mb is added. I am sure my ViewModel is not referencing the View.

Any suggestions to solve this problem or explain to me why this is so?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I used the dotTrace memory profiler and found that there is no reference from the ViewModel. All references to the "data" variable are UI objects. Most of it are from template. How should I correctly solve this issue?

Comment: Is there any code-behind for the view that attaches to an event ofthe ViewModel or other non UI object?

Comment: nope. Only normal data bindings.

Comment: I would suggest using .NET memory profiler if that's possible for you. It should give you a straight answer to what is causing it to not be collected.

Comment: did you get a outofmemory exception? are view and viewmodel connected by a datatemplate?

Comment: Do you have any event handlers wired up in the View Model (naughty)? These will cause the View to stay alive.

Comment: One other thing, you can use PerfMon (which has the benefit of being free) to monitor the GC. Note that since you are allocating 50MB, this goes on the Large Object Heap (LOH) as its over 85K.

Comment: Does the ViewModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged, as it can cause a memory leak if it doesn't?

Comment: I dun have any event handlers wired up. My ViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged. I will try use a profiler and see what happens.

Comment: @blindmeis what do you mean by View and ViewModel are connected by datatemplate? do you have any information/article about this? i believe it is to do with the templates as I checked on the Profiler, there are template UI objects still referencing to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this tool it helped me a lot. http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/ (there is a 10 day trial)

Answer (score 0):

Not implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on classes that are bound to in the UI can cause a memory leak.  See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938416/en-us